# Can't access images on pornographic website - 401 error

Tags: windows-10, internet, internet-connection

I have an account on a pornographic website. This is *not* a discussion of the content of that website - this is a technical issue. If this is still not allowed, please tell me - I couldn't find anything specifically regarding asking for help with technical issues on such websites in the terms of service.

So, anyway, my issue is this: I can view and download videos on the website, but cannot view or download images. I've opened the console (by pressing F12) and apparently I'm getting a 401 authentication error. I've already tried all sorts of things - clearing my cache and cookies for every website, for the website specifically, having my password on the website changed, using different browsers, etc., and nothing so far has solved my problem. I'm sure there's some sort of issue with network settings or something on my computer, because I can access images on my phone with no issues.

EDIT: Progress report - I can see images on the mobile version of the site, whether or not I'm actually using a mobile device, and I cannot see images on the desktop version of the site, whether or not I'm actually using a desktop pc. This only confuses me more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not fixed when changing browsers, disabling extensions or using incognito mode, and you've found that it works fine with the mobile site, chances are it's a bug with their desktop site and there is nothing you can do.

From there you have two options, report the bug to their customer support or wait it out and see if it gets fixed. Communication between website users and website developers is crucial, sometimes broken things can go unnoticed!

Comment: Yeah, that does seem like the most likely situation. I'll try to notify their customer support as soon as I can.